# What extra features has the Android Youtube application over the HTML one?

Tags: youtube

It seems the HTML Youtube application has all the features the Android Youtube application has. I want to remove the Android Youtube application. But I want to make sure that I will not lose any feature.

Do you know if the installed Android Youtube application has any extra features that the web Youtube does not have?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't lose any viewing features. The YouTube application is simply a way to make it easier to view and search, without having to load the entire html pages. Probably the only feature you wouldn't be able to take advantage of (and i don't know this for sure) is uploading. You can use the YouTube app to upload videos you've taken to your own YouTube account. And like i said, you might be able to do this through the browser, but the app is just a way to make it easier. Simplification is key.

Comment: I also saw that the browser crashes when uploading big videos: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15571

Answer (score 1):

It has one major feature, at least on my phone, I can't watch playlists on the site, but I can from the app. I find that it loads faster and it's interface is much easier to use.